# Quasar dynamically generate input fields Vue

Tags: javascript, frontend, quasar-framework, quasar

I want to dynamically create input fields based on the length of an array.

For example:
if the array is `["blue", "green", "yellow"]`

then I would like to generate 3 different quasar inputs based on the array.

How would I go about this, which is basically dynamically generating HTML code, is it possible via Quasar?

Comment: use `v-for` and learn vue by the way: https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html

Comment: For whatever reason this question was downvoted. That's the toxic environment we strive to eliminate in our everyday work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "v-for" to run on the Array items, it should look something like that :

```
<div v-for="arrItem in array" :key="arrItem.key">
<q-input type="text" v-model="model" :color="arrItem"/>
</div>
```